# store input field attributes id, name, type in angular 6

Tags: json, angular, angular6, angular-forms

I want to store & send the input field attributes id, name, type & value; to my server. 
I am able to store the "name: value," in json format & send to server.

I want to send the input data in below format:

```
{ 
   "iEntityId":2,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "value":"some name",
         "name":"sSupplierName",
         "type":0
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "value":"some code",
         "name":"sSupplierCode",
         "type":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my input field:

```
<input [type]="q.sFieldType" 
       [formControlName]="q.sFieldName" 
       [id]="q.sFieldName" 
       class="form-control m-input">
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Can you try to add some details ?  What's blocking you ?

Comment: You have the json data from the html form, you can use `httpClient` module to make request on server.

Comment: DO you have multiple input or a single input

Comment: I have multiple input and I wanted to send the input attributes as a json string in the given format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this, we just need set a json object and then input the dynamic fields that are used in the input attributes.